# Proof of return for Japanese visa

Tags: visas, japanese-visitors

I am an Indian national, currently working at a software company. I will be leaving it on August 15. On August 16, I'll be traveling to Kyoto for a summer school where I'll stay until September 2. Generally, a Japanese visa asks for NOC from the employer. Given that I will be unemployed by the time I travel, will that raise suspicion? How do I work around this?

I'll be going to London on September 15 for a Master's degree. Can I show proof of that for return?

Comment: It's OK. Do show that (your admissions letter, your enrollment letter etc). Show proof of finances. Show a return ticket. But then we can't guarantee anything because we don't work for the Japanese MoFA :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [short-term visa to Japan for Indian nationals](http://www.in.emb-japan.go.jp/short_term%20visas.html) no longer requires evidence of employment:

> **SHORT-TERM VISA**
>
> (A stay of up to 90 days for touruism, business, attending conference, visiting friends, etc., that does not include paid activities.)
>
> **(1) TOURIST VISA** - Required Documents
>
> **Self-arranged visit**
>
> 1. Application with Photo;
> 2. Passport;
> 3. Travel Booking (Travel itinerary and Hotel Booking);
> 4. Document to prove ability to pay for travel expenses: 
>      -- (a) Latest Income Tax Return; 
>     
>      -- (b) Bank Statements of last 6 months

Supporting evidence would include documents from the 2-week program in Japan, the London program, and flight tickets to your next destination.